# UPDATE three table in one single UPDATE query

Tags: mysql

I have three tables like this:

1/ *topics* table:

```
topic_id    category_id    subject    
   1             1         first
   2             3         second
   3             2         third
```

2/ *categories* table:

```
category_id    cat_name
     1         art
     2         math
```

The *topics* table is linked to the *categories* table by the foreign key `category_id`.

3/ *article* table:

```
article_id    topic_id    body      date
    1            1        blabla   7/20/2014
    2            1        a reply  7/22/2014
```

The *article* table is linked to the *topics* table by the foreign key `topic_id`. This table stores both the topic's description (`article_id # 1`) and its possible repli(es) (`article_id #2`)

I have a form that enables the topic owner to **update** the `subject` in table 1, `category name` in table 2, and the `body` in the table 3.

Assume that I can **validate** the three required elements such as *subject*, *cat_name*, and *body* successfully, and I have got them from the form submission and assigned to the three variables like this:

```
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$cat_name = $_POST['cat_name'];
$body = $_POST['body'];
```

Now, I would like to update the `topic_id #1` (`$tid = $_GET['tid'];`), whose subject, category name and body are stored in three different table.

Can you help me to write a single `UPDATE` query that can perform this requirement, please?

Thank you very much!

P/S: I can write the UPDATE query for one table only. Now, I get stuck at the `multible-table update` query.

**[EDITED]**: In order to help clarify the question, I would like to add a piece of information as follows:

As the `UPDATE` is conducted by the topic's owner (non-owner cannot do it), the `article_id#2` here, for example, might/ might not belong to the same owner/user of the certain `topic_id`. So please consider that the `UPDATE` process just focus on the article_id that **firstly** goes with the topic_id to be updated.

Comment: I presume this is MySQL? The update-join syntax differs between RDBMS.

Comment: This seems like a terrible database design. The Subject should be a column in the Artical table. The Categories and Topics should then be used a hierarchical structure for "filing" the Articles. You could then just update the Article table to change the Subject, Body and Category/Topic filing.

Comment: Though the m/dd/yyyy date format suggests maybe MS SQL Server (and if it _is_ mysql, that should be made into  a proper datetime type rather than a varchar type)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Yes, you are correct!. This my MySQL.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Yes. And I will correct it. I would use `date datetime NOT NULL,` .Can you help with the UPDATE query, please?

Comment: Last example on the MySQL update syntax page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html It shows you how to join multiple tables for updating.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are accessing both `$_POST` vals and `$_GET['tid']` in _the same HTTP request_ so all are known at the time you want to do the update?

Comment: @the_pete: I already read the link you provided. However, this is the very first time I've encountered this `UPDATE syntax` level. So, a full answer will be very much appreciated!

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Yes, I do. I can do the `GET` and `POST` to perform the `name=value pair` for my `edit.php?tid=1`, for example. My problem is the UPDATE query.

Comment: @Eric_ph Another question - in your sample, you have two articles with the same `topic_id`.  Is the new `$_POST['body']` intended to update _both_ of them?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: No, please focus on the `airticle_id #1` only because the `airticle_id# 2` is the topic's reply, which may belong to another user who replied to the topic.

Comment: @Eric_ph Does anything in the `$_POST` identify that article?  If not, it increases the complexity of this significantly (to retrieve the first article grouped by topic_id)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59665/discussion-between-eric-ph-and-michael-berkowski).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL's [multi-table `UPDATE` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) follows the general format:

```
UPDATE
  t1
  JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
SET
  t1.col1 = 'new value',
  t2.col2 = 'new value'
WHERE
  <some condition>
```

You'll want to join via `topic_id` to gather all your columns for update. Chiefly here, the complexity resides in the fact that the data model lists articles and replies in the same table, with only their positions per `article.topic_id` group to identify them. That means you'll need to join on a subquery which returns the first (`MIN()`) `article_id` per `topic_id` group to identify which article's `body` should be updated.

```
UPDATE
  topics t
  INNER JOIN categories c ON t.category_id = c.category_id
  INNER JOIN article a ON t.topic_id = a.topic_id
  /** 
   Subquery retrieves the lowest article_id per topic_id
   The INNER JOIN here will cause only one record from `article` to match
   and be modified.
   */
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT topic_id, MIN(article_id) AS article_id
    FROM article
    GROUP BY topic_id
    /* Join the subquery against `article` by `article_id` */
  ) first_per_topic ON a.article_id = first_per_topic.article_id
SET
  /* Supply the new values */
  t.subject = ?,
  c.cat_name = ?,
  a.body = ?
WHERE 
  /* Identify the topic_id in the WHERE clause */
  t.topic_id = ?
```

Above, I have used `?` placeholders assuming a MySQLi or PDO prepared statement (recommended). Substitute your new values as necessary.

A note about these date formats `7/22/2014`... Unless this is just sample data you typed into the question, it suggests you might not be using [a proper `DATE` data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) on that column.  It is recommended to use a `DATE` type to allow MySQL to use its built-in date processing abilities.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I will employ it soon and give you feedback. By the way, I use DATETIME type for the `articles` table. Is it good? Note: I am using `MySQLi` for my coding process because `PDO prepared statement` is still advanced to a newbie like me.

Comment: @Eric_ph Yes, DATETIME will be fine. I was just concerned when I saw the format you represented here, as that often implies the use of a varchar column.  (now is the time to start getting the hang of prepared statements - they make a large difference in security, PDO is a little easier to work with than MySQLi for prepared statements, in my opinion)

Comment: I just tested this. It's marvellous!

Comment: @Eric_ph Hey I'm glad to hear it worked out. Happy to help and good luck.